# Writing a filter to extract multiple occurrences of an event

Tags: logstash

I am reading about log stash and I am able to understand how log stash can extract multiple lines (and stack traces) by means of filters.

My requirement is of a filter which returns results only if an event occurs say 10 times.

So if an event occurs 1 2 or 3 times then ignore but when it had occurred say 10 times then return results.

Comment: Have you seen the metrics filter?  http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/metrics